# Sydney Baggage Transfer

Tags: luggage, sydney, air-india

I have booked a flight from Auckland to Delhi with 1 PNR via Sydney in Air India.

So the flight from Auckland to Sydney is from Qantas and then Air India from Sydney to Delhi.

When I checked with Airlines they are saying you need to recheckin at Sydney as you will get next boarding pass in Sydney.

I have 2 hours transit time, is it enough to take the second flight or if yes then how?

Comment: Did you book these as one ticket, through one airline?

Comment: When you said you "checked with Airlines", do you mean at check-in, or did you ask them in advance?

Comment: Note that Indian nationals need a visa to transit via Australia even if they stay airside (don't have to clear immigration, collect bags, check-in...).

Answer (score 5):

Standard procedure for this type of connection (single PNR, international to international) is that your luggage is checked trough from AKL to DEL and that you don't need to clear immigration and/or customs in Sydney.

Normally you would get both boarding passes when checking in in AKL. However , its possible that Qantas can't issue an Air India boarding pass. In this case you need to go an Air India transfer desk when you arrive in Sydney. That's probably the case here and 2 hours should be fine for that.

> they are saying you need to recheckin at Sydney as you will get next boarding pass in Sydney.

You should clarify what exactly they mean by "recheckin" as the term is ambiguous. It could mean that

1. You need to get a boarding pass airside at a transfer desk
2. You need to get a boarding pass landside at a regular check in counter
3. You need to collect your bags and re-check them

2 hours would definitely NOT be enough for #2 or #3.

Comment: Note that while Qantas hide it very well, they actually have an interline agreement with Air India, so they should indeed be able to issue boarding passes and check luggage through to the final destination.

Comment: FWIW: I had plenty of cases where bags were checked through but boarding passes could not be issued and we needed to go to the transfer desk. Apparently bags are easier than boarding passes (perhaps because of specific doc checks?)

Comment: I believe the main difficulty for boarding passes is when your first flight is very long and/or you have a very long connection and/or you check-in early for your that flight, and thus end up before the check-in window opens for the next flight. There are also a few cases where there are additional security checks (for flights to the US or Israel for instance) to be done before the boarding pass is issued.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is a bit confusing, because Qantas apparently do not acknowledge the fact they have an interline agreement with Air India.

Qantas [tell us](https://www.qantas.com/agencyconnect/ca/en/policy-and-guidelines/baggage-information/interline-and-through-checked-baggage.html#when-can-my-customers-bags-be-through-checked):

> #### When can my Customers Bags be Through Checked?
>
> If the customers flights are all held in the same booking and are ticketed on Qantas or Qantas/Emirates and/or a oneworld airline, the baggage will be transferred between the flights and the customer will receive a boarding pass at check-in for their onward flights.
>
> **If the customers flights are all held in the same booking and the first flight is Qantas and the other flights are not Qantas, Emirates or a oneworld airline, baggage transfer onto the next flight depends on whether a specific agreement exists between Qantas and that airline**. The customer will be advised by Qantas staff at check-in.
>
> To assist you to determine if customers baggage will be interlined and boarding passes issued by Airport staff, please refer to the table below:
>
> |  | One PNR | One PNR | Separate PNR | Separate PNR |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Scenario | Boarding Pass | Baggage | Boarding Pass | Baggage |
> | QF to/from QF | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | QF to/from EK | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
> | QF to/from oneworld | Yes | Yes | No^ | No^ |
> | QF to/from non - oneworld | **Yes*** | **Yes*** | No | No |

You're in the bolded scenario (One PNR, QF to/form non-one world). So what does the `*` mean?

> `*` Provided Qantas Interline and Inter-Airline Through Check-in (IATCI) agreements exist.

Now, you can scour the Qantas site as much as you want, I haven't found a single reference to Air India, including in any of the partner airline pages.

But [Expertflyer](https://www.expertflyer.com/air/travelInformation.do) (subscription required, but there's a free trial available) tells us for QF:

> Interline AgreementsShare Results
>
> E-Ticket Interline Agreements
>
> ```
> AA        AB        AC        AE        AF        AI        
> AM        AP        AS        AT        AV        AY        
> AZ        A3        BA        BD        BE        BG        
> BI        BL        BP        BR        BW        CA        
> CC        CI        CM        CO        CX        CZ        
> DL        EI        EK        ET        EY        FI        
> FJ        FM        FQ        FZ        GA        GF        
> GK        G3        HA        HG        HU        HX        
> HY        IB        IE        IG        JC        JJ        
> JK        JL        JP        JQ        KC        KE        
> KL        KM        KQ        KU        LA        LG        
> LH        LO        LP        LR        LX        LY        
> MA        MF        MH        MI        MK        MR        
> MS        MU        MX        NC        NF        NH        
> NU        NZ        OA        OK        OM        OS        
> OT        OU        OZ        O6        PC        PG        
> PR        PX        PZ        QR        QV        RA        
> RJ        RO        SA        SB        SK        SN        
> SQ        SU        SV        SW        S2        S7        
> TA        TG        TK        TL        TN        TP        
> UA        UK        UL        US        UU        VF        
> VN        VS        VT        VX        WS        WY        
> XL        XR        YV        3K        4M        4Z        
> 6E        8M        9B        9W
> ```
>
> Paper Ticket and Baggage Interline Agreements
>
> ```
> MAY ISSUE TICKETS INCLUDING
>    AA  AC  AE  AF  AH  AI  AM  AS  AT  AV  AX  AY  AZ  A3  
>    BA  BE  BG  BI  BL  BP  BR  BW  CA  CI  CJ  CL  CM  CX  
>    CZ  DL  EI  EK  ET  EW  EY  FI  FJ  FM  FZ  GA  GF  GK  
>    G3  HA  HG  HM  HU  HX  HY  IB  IC  IE  IG  JC  JJ  JL  
>    JO  JP  JQ  KA  KC  KE  KL  KM  KQ  KU  K6  LA  LG  LH  
>    LO  LP  LR  LX  LY  MF  MH  MI  MK  MR  MS  MU  NF  NH  
>    NU  NX  NZ  OA  OK  OM  OS  OT  OU  OZ  O6  PG  PR  PX  
>    PZ  QR  QV  RA  RJ  RO  SA  SB  SK  SN  SQ  SU  SV  SW  
>    S2  S7  TA  TG  TK  TL  TN  TP  UA  UK  UL  UU  VN  VS  
>    VT  VX  WS  WY  XL  YM  2A  3K  4M  4Q  4Z  6E  8M  9B  
>    9W                                                      
>
> MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO
>    AA  AC  AE  AF  AH  AI  AS  AT  AV  AX  AY  AZ  A3  BA  
>    BE  BG  BI  BL  BP  BR  BW  CA  CI  CJ  CL  CM  CX  CZ  
>    DL  EI  EK  ET  EW  EY  FI  FJ  FM  FZ  GA  GF  GK  G3  
>    HA  HG  HM  HU  HX  HY  IB  IC  IE  IG  JC  JJ  JL  JO  
>    JP  JQ  KA  KC  KE  KL  KM  KQ  KU  K6  LA  LH  LO  LP  
>    LR  LX  LY  ME  MF  MH  MI  MK  MR  MS  MU  NF  NH  NU  
>    NX  NZ  OA  OK  OM  OS  OT  OU  OZ  O6  PG  PR  PX  PZ  
>    QR  QV  RA  RO  SA  SB  SK  SN  SQ  SU  SV  SW  S2  S7  
>    TA  TG  TK  TL  TN  TP  UA  UK  UL  UU  VN  VS  VX  WS  
>    WY  XL  YM  2A  3K  4M  4Q  4Z  8M  9W
> ```

And `AI` is clearly listed. Qantas is also listed as an interline partner [on the Air India website](https://www.airindia.com/in/en/destinations/partner-airlines/booking-partners.html) though contrary to other airlines, they don't give details.

Unless they publish incorrect data on the GDSes, they have an interline agreement, and they should check you through.

Note however, and that may be the source of the confusion, that while you should be able to stay airside (not going through immigration, not claiming bags, not going to check-in), Indian citizens need a visa to transit through Australia. Maybe someone mixed up the two (in many places you only need a visa if you can't stay airside). This does not apply to New Zealand citizens or any others listed [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa).